# How to fix TypeError: Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to add an empty column in my dataset on colab but it gives me this error. When I'm trying to run it on my local machine it works perfectly fine.

Does anybody have a possible solution for this?

My code:

```
dataframe["Comp"] = ''
dataframe["Negative"] = ''
dataframe["Neutral"] = ''
dataframe["Positive"] = ''
dataframe
```

Error message:

````
TypeError: Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty```
````

Comment: Did you added pandas? Your code is working fine in Colab

Comment: yes I import pandas.

Comment: Add more details to your question and include the Full code!

Answer (score 0):

I find out that was due to freq of my datetimeindex was set as

```
pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty object at 0x7fb22dd1e2c8>
```

I used `.asfreq('H')` to set it correctly.